# Set-acl unauthorized access

Tags: powershell, acl, ntfs

My script which basically should copy folders from template and apply acl from it throws following error:
I've setup correct ntfs rights on share and checked SeSecurityPermission

*Part of log file below*

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Username: domain\project_creation
RunAs User: domain\project_creation
PSVersion: 5.1.17134.590
**********************
Transcript started, output file is \\srv\Projekty\script_files\logs\20212004-1520.log
Set-Acl : Nastąpiła próba wykonania nieautoryzowanej operacji.
At \\srv\Projekty\script_files\make_project_folder_with_subfolders.ps1:168 char:72
+ ...          Get-Acl "$root\PROJEKT TEMPLATE\$folder" | Set-Acl "$folder"
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\\srv\Proj...ty_przed_oferta:String) [Set-Acl], UnauthorizedAccess
Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAclCommand
```

```
                #Variables
                $Project_name = $Project_name_tmp.Text
                $log_name = $Project_year + $Project_name + "_" + $date +".log"
                $log_path = "$root\logs\$log_name"
                $id_tmp = Get-ChildItem .\$Project_year | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
                $year_tmp = $Project_year.Substring(2)
                $id = $id_tmp + 1
                $project_folder_full_location = $root +"\"+ $Project_year+"\" +$id+"_"+ $year_tmp +"_" +$Project_name

                    try{
                        Copy-Item -Path "$root\PROJEKT TEMPLATE" -Destination $project_folder_full_location -Recurse
                        Set-Location $project_folder_full_location 
                        foreach($folder in Get-ChildItem){

#Line that contains error                           
Get-Acl "$root\PROJEKT TEMPLATE\$folder" | Set-Acl "$folder"
                        
}
                        Get-Acl "$root\PROJEKT TEMPLATE" | Set-Acl "$project_folder_full_location"
                    Write-host "Struktura katalogowa została utworzona"
       
                }catch{
                    Write-Error $_
                    pause
                }
        }
        Stop-transcript
```

Could you please check it out?
The user that's changing rights to that folder is an owner

```
Path        Owner                 Access                                                                                                                                                      
----        -----                 ------                                                                                                                                                      
9_21_testv6 domain\project_creation domain\project_creation Allow  FullControl...                                                                                                                 



PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\srv\Projekty\2021\9_21_testv6> (Get-Acl).Access


FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : domain\project_creation
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None
```

```
PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\srv\Projekty\2021\9_21_testv6> cd .\01_Dokumenty_przed_oferta

PS Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\srv\Projekty\2021\9_21_testv6\01_Dokumenty_przed_oferta> (Get-Acl).Access


FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : domain\project_creation
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : None
PropagationFlags  : None
```

Comment: Does changing `\\srv` to `\\srv.your.domain.local` or `\\ip.add.res.s` make a difference?  For `Set-Acl`, does it help to specify `-LiteralPath "$folder"` instead of relying on the default -Path parameter?  Also, if you are auditing security failures, what is being reported in the Security audit event log?

Comment: It was caused by not having enough privileges.
https://helgeklein.com/setacl/faq/
Currently I'm trying to find out what are the lowest ntfs permissions required to run set-acl cmdlet